# Split time from date value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time, split

I am getting value of DOB and its includes time also

```
  here is the value :-


 var date=`2017-05-21T00:00:00`
```

so how can i remove time from that value to display date only.

Comment: `date.split(/[a-zA-Z]/)[0];`

Comment: Anything to do with dates and times, have a look at momentjs - otherwise you could split on `T`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.split()` to get what you are looking for

`.split()` turns the values into an array starting at 0.

so if we did `date = date.split('T')` then `data[0]` is = "2017-05-21" and `data[1]` is = "00:00:00"

```js
var date = "2017-05-21T00:00:00";
date = date.split('T')[0];

console.log(date)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well another answer to a question which can be voted to closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can format it like

```
var mydate = new Date('2017-05-21T00:00:00');
var dd = mydate.getDate();
var mm = mydate.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = mydate.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd;
} 
if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm;
} 
var dateformat = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
alert(dateformat);
```